# Fitting the same glmer model to multiple subsets of the same data

Tags: r, lme4

I am trying to address basically the same question as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58803605/quick-way-to-fit-the-same-mixed-model-to-multiple-dataframes-or-subsets-in-r), but I can't seem to apply this to `glmer` instead of `lmer`.

I have a rather complex model that looks something like this:

```
 mod1 <- glmer(outcome ~
                 var1*var0 +
                 var2*var0 +
                 var3+
                 var4+
                 (1+var0|subj),
               family=binomial("logit"),

          control=glmerControl(calc.derivs=FALSE,
                                    optimizer="bobyqa",
                                    optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)),
               data=subset(mydata, var5 == T))
```

Which I want to split by another variable, `var6`, of which there are 7 levels, and run this model for each subset.

To illustrate using the `sleepstudy` data, and using the edits to create two new variables - `Group` as in the post I link above, as well as `sex`:

```
 data(sleepstudy)
 sleepstudy$group <- car::recode(sleepstudy$Subject,
   "c('308','309','310','330','331','332','333','334') = 'group1'; 
     c('335','337','349','350','351','352','369','370','371','372') = 'group2'")
 sleepstudy$sex <- car::recode(sleepstudy$Subject,
                   "c('308','310','331','333','335','349','351','369','371') = 'm';
   c('309','330','332','334','337','350','352','370','372') = 'f'")
 
 model<-glmer(group~Days+Reaction+(1|Subject), 
                family=binomial("logit"),
                          data=sleepstudy)
```

In this example I would want to run this model twice, split by `sex`. Is there a way I can do this quickly and efficiently to extract the coefficients from each model?

Answer (score 2):

With `tidyverse`, this would be:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom.mixed)
library(lme4)
 sleepstudy$group <- car::recode(sleepstudy$Subject,
   "c('308','309','310','330','331','332','333','334') = 'group1'; 
     c('335','337','349','350','351','352','369','370','371','372') = 'group2'")
 sleepstudy$sex <- car::recode(sleepstudy$Subject,
                   "c('308','310','331','333','335','349','351','369','371') = 'm';
   c('309','330','332','334','337','350','352','370','372') = 'f'")
(sleepstudy
   |> split(sleepstudy$sex)
   |> purrr::map(~glmer(group~Days+Reaction+(1|Subject), 
                family=binomial("logit"),
                data = .))
   |> purrr::map_dfr(~tidy(., effects = "fixed"), .id = "sex")
)
```

(hardcore tidyverse users would use `nest()` + `mutate()` + `unnest()` to make list-columns, similar to [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55249787/190277).)

In base R, after using `split()`, you can

```r
(sleepstudy
   |> split(sleepstudy$sex)
   |> lapply( \(.) glmer(group~Days+Reaction+(1|Subject), 
                family=binomial("logit"),
                data = .))
   |> lapply(fixef)
)
```

(you could also `lapply(summary)` for the last step).  Running `do.call("rbind", ...)` on the results will produce a data frame (but you won't have the convenience of having the `sex` variable included in the result).

Comment: Thank you! This is great and works perfectly but for one issue - even with the id specified in the code, I do not see the ID in the output. So I can't tell which subset matches to which set of model outputs.

Comment: I had a misplaced parenthesis.  Try again?